# How to filter random number generator and not include 0

Tags: racket

How do I fix the `random: expects (or/c (integer-in 1 4294967087) pseudo-random-generator?) or a pseudo-random-generator, given 0` error?

```
(require 2htdp/universe)
(require 2htdp/image)

(define-struct sample(x))
(define BACKGROUND (empty-scene 100 100))
(define CIRCLE (ellipse 10 10 "solid" "red"))

(define (rand d)
  (random d))

(define (randoll d)
  (cond [(even? (rand d))(rand d)]
        [(< (rand d) 6)7]
        [(= (rand d) 0)7]
        [else 7]))

(define (main ws)
  (big-bang ws
      (on-tick randoll)
      (to-draw render)))

(define (render d)
      (place-image CIRCLE (randoll d) 6 BACKGROUND))
```

> (main 100)
>   random: expects (or/c (integer-in 1 4294967087) pseudo-random-generator?) or a pseudo-random-generator, given 0
>
> Was expecting for it to continuously changing places at even numbers but this happened

Answer (score 1, accepted):

How about adding `1` to the parameter passed to `random`? as long as the input is `>= 0` it'll work fine - the error you're receiving is simply stating that you can't pass `0` as parameter to `random`:

```
(define (rand d)
  (random (+ d 1)))
```

By the way, `randoll` doesn't look right. Why do you test if the random value is even, just to return another random value, which we don't know if it's going to be even? And it appears that if the random value is zero or in all the other cases you just want to return `7`. Better try this, if it fits what you intended:

```
(define (randoll d)
  (let ([r (rand d)])   ; call `rand` exactly once
    (cond [(zero? r) 7] ; 0 is even, so check this first
          [(even? r) r] ; return `r` only if it's even
          [else 7])))   ; default case
```

I'm not sure what's the expected range of values for `randoll`, but it looks to me that most of the time it'll just return `7`. Is this what you want?

Comment: I was trying to make an on-tick function slower thats why I used an even? function. I need a random generator for an x coordinate so I can put an object somewhere at random

Comment: @DanGal I see, but are you sure about what's the range of values that get passed to `randoll`? it seems that you'll be returning `7` half of the time.

Comment: Yea if it goes 0 id like to position the image at x coordinate 7 so The image will not be cropped. Anyways, is there a function to just put a range? Like random [6-94] for example?

Comment: @DanGal have you read the [docs](https://docs.racket-lang.org/reference/generic-numbers.html#%28part._.Random_.Numbers%29) of the function you're using? that's exactly what it does! For example, to generate numbers in the range [6, 94] do this: `(random 6 95)`

Comment: Tried it tho. It says random only expects 1 argument even tho I read the racket docs and what u said is true idk why its not working lol